# Vias in the Input and output path

Tags: level-translation

I have designed a custom level translator using [SN74LVC1T45](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwj_2c-Igf3lAhUCXn0KHWfZAZAQFjAAegQIBBAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fsn74lvc1t45&usg=AOvVaw3pbgT92HKiEzszLt0xrm54). I have placed chips on top and bottom to reduce the board size and because of this, I have used vias for the input and outputs for the bottom chip.

So is it okay to use vias in input and output path?

The board operating frequency is 10Hz to 20Mhz.

Comment: what is the edge rise and fall time? that is what counts. A via ia about 1 nanoHenry +-. If you model the trace as 1 nanoHenry in series with 50 ohms, the time constant of L/R or 1nH/50ohm === 20 picoSeconds.

Comment: The chip has different rise and fall time for different voltage configuration

Comment: Imagine that your <20 MHz pulse has 3 ns rise time.  What could possibly cause ringing and false triggers?  What would the Q need to be or Reactance / RdsOn ratio? ... to generate that false trigger. How do you reduce that effect by reducing L/C ratio of traces?  The via inductance is added to trace inductance.

Comment: I am a newbie to the PCB designing, so i am not bale understand your points